# Application fail to exit when a runtime created object is used

Tags: vb.net

I'm using vb.net 2013, and I have configured Shutdown mode to "When last form is closed".

On my main form, I have a menu item which has this code to close the application:

```
Application.Exit
```

Everything is working fine, except one case:

When I open a specific form, where a `Combobox` is created on runtime and I've used `Addhandler` to subscribe to several events.

The `combobox` is created when pressing a button.

When I open this form and I don't create the `combobox`, everything is working ok. If the `combobox` is created, when I close this form and try to close the application using the menu item, nothing happens. The application is not closed and no error message is displayed. (the same situation occurs when I try to close the main form with "x" button)

On the form's (where I have the `combobox`) close event , I tried to put a line of code:

```
MyCombobox.dispose()
```

But the situation is the same.

What can I do? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What I do from my little experience is

1.) remove the MyCombobox from its parent control (I'm think this is in your combobox close event).
2.) set the MyCombobox to Nothing
3.) Dispose() it.

```
MyCombobox = Nothing 
MyCombobox.Dispose()
```

It would be useful to see some part of your code for the close event so we can help you check. More power to you!

Update based on OP's comment:
I have read the following from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx

From this, it is important to note that:

The Form.Closed and Form.Closing events are not raised when the Application.Exit method is called to exit your application. If you have validation code in either of these events that must be executed, you should call the Form.Close method for each open form individually before calling the Exit method.

Comment: I've already done all these , but not working. I have no special code in close event. Only these lines for combobox.

Comment: sorry but we are talking for different forms. The main form has the menuitem that call the application.exit. The form that has the combobox is another form that is closed as any other form and the closing and closed event are raised normally. After this form is closed , I use the menuitem to close the application. But at this point I have the probles I've described.

Comment: Hi, I think I slightly get the picture but can you give a snippet of the sub being used for the menuitem? I will try to simulate the situation and hopefully come with a more useful solution :)

Comment: the menuitem sub's has only 1 instruction : Application.Exit.